# How To Make A DiscordJS Selfbot Join A Server Without The Use Of Discord Invites Api?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

First of all, I know that Self bots are against the TOS of Discord. So Please Don't Say That.

I have been trying to make a discord self bot to join a server using an Invite link.
So the most known method for this was using the discord invites API with a XMLHttpRequest. That Actually Works. But after that by a few seconds the account asks for a phone verification number.
Which I think due to the changes Discord had made with their API.

Code:

```js
const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('POST', `https://discordapp.com/api/v7/invites/${invite}`);
        x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "token");
        x.send();
```

So I was thinking about something else. Like making a request to the link of the invite itself, and inserting the discord token in it. Just like what does this does. But instead of using the API Directly We'd Just Use The "discord.gg/link" Thing.

Is this possible? And If it is How can it be made. I thought about puppeteer but it doesn't go really well with discord.js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find self bot code online in github repos, most of the code doesnt work - but if you put enough time into it you can get it to work

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused as to what a selfbot is - you don't need to invite it by request, log into the selfbot account and join any server from an invite and the account will join.

If by

> join a server using an Invite link

you mean automatically join servers remotely, I would be reluctant to help any further since it is likely that you are aiming to use a large amount of bots to raid or spam servers or users - which is illegal due to the laws surrounding spam and botnets.

please don't commit crimes surrounding the Discord API, its just selfish, pointless and dangerous.

Comment: I know what a selfbot is. What I am trying to make is something else. I am trying to make a program to control my other account with my main one. Not for raiding or anything. I am not into any big servers or anything.

Comment: You did not mention this in your original question, but I'm glad your plans are not malicious. I also don't know what you mean by `control my other account with my main one` mean - if you could clarify what you mean it would be useful.

Comment: Just like how you control a bot. Send messages to your friends, receive messages. React to messages, Join Voice channels, Play music. Etc..

Comment: just run a self bot, like literally any other bot - you just need to find the user's token